# ReferenceError: openMyModalNew is not defined error in Ijoomla Guru 5

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal

Little time ago I install Ijoomla Guru 5 and only now I realize that tutorials not opening in modal window. 
I get error ReferenceError: openMyModalNew is not defined. As right now I haven't access to their forum I can't ask them about that.
Maybe some of you faced with this problem or know how to resolve that.

Comment: A link to the live website might help. Could this be a MooTools / jQuery conflict? Have you tried updating to the latest version?

Comment: Here is website. http://mgtuts.com/
Actually after updating to last version I get this problem. I try to install and check all plugins but not result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like jQuery is loading before MooTools and this might be the cause of the issue.

Force MooTools to load first by adding the following line high up in the HEAD section of the template `index.php` file:

```
JHTML::_('behavior.framework', true);
```

Alternatively, you may be able to fix the load order using a third party extension such as [jQuery Easy](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy) or disable MooTools if you are not using it via [MooTools Enabler/Disabler](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/mootools-enabler-disabler) or similar.